# How to model the sampling distribution of the sample sum

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

I'm stuck on a stats problem and am wondering if someone can point out the error in my logic.

Imagine you are planning for a camping trip for 50 people. Each person consumes 2.0 lb of food per day on average, with a standard deviation of 0.7 lb.  What is the least amount of food you need to bring to be 97.5% sure that you will have enough food?

**First line of reasoning:**
The standard deviation for the average amount consumed by one person is **0.7/sqrt(50)**

The standard deviation for the total amount consumed by all 50 people is **sqrt(50)*0.7**

The desired answer is thus **2.0*50 + 2*sqrt(50)*0.7.**

**Second line of reasoning:**

SD(n*x) = n*SD(x). Thus, the standard deviation for the amount consumed by 50 people is **50*0.7**

The desired solution is then **2.0*50 + 2*50*0.7**

I know the second line of reasoning is wrong.  Could someone explain why?  Thanks!

** EDIT **

I think the error is that the standard deviation for the amount consumed by 50 people is not 50*0.7, because the people are independent.

VAR(amount consumed by 50 people) != VAR(50 * amount consumed by one person)

Comment: I think you've got it. There's a difference between 50 different people, and 50 copies of the same person!